# What is this IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

[image]

The markings at the top say "TC104-1", and at the bottom "9041".

It was found in a box of random ICs and parts, and googling hasn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: Googling "TC104 ccd" brings up useful results.  That would be hard to guess if one doesn't recognize that chip as a linear CCD sensor.

Comment: The 9041 is probably a date code: 41st week of 1990.  These sensor have been used in astronomy since the 1980s (at least).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks to be a Texas Instrument TC 104-1, CCD line scan sensor.

From [Data Sheet Archive](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/shortform-datasheet/TC104-1.html) I was able to find:

**TC104-1**

- Linear CCD Image Array - DR 1000:1,WhiteRefer.Elements
- Vertical Pixel Count=1
- Horizontal Pixel Count=3456
- Vertical Pixel Dimension (m)=10.7u
- Horizontal Pixel Dimension (m)=10.7u
- Horizontal Dimension (m)=36.9m
- Vertical Dimension (m)=10.7u
- Vsup Nom.(V) Supply Voltage=14
- P(D) Max.(W) Power Dissipation=112m
- Package=DIP

These types of chips are typically used for [automated inspection cameras](http://www.euresys.com/Products/grablink/ADRTechnology.asp) or flat bed scanners.  They are a 1D CCD sensor.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding the datasheet.

Comment: These specs seem consistent with someone else [looking for these](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/sci.optics/5Sse9Uln_NE/H9xfIDm86pkJ) back in 1995.

Comment: I dont suppose anyone can find the datasheet could they?